# Вызов метода с помощью Reflection java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, исключения, рефлексия

Хочу вызвать метод с помощью Reflection,но выдает ошибку. Не могли бы Вы объяснить в чем проблема? Спасибо!

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
        Class cls = Class.forName("Main");
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("toSting");
        method.invoke(obj,"null");
    }
    public void toSting(String a){
        System.out.println("hi "+ a);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main.toSting()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2553)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь получить метод toString(), т.е. без аргументов. Такого у Вас нет, отсюда и ошибка. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(Main.class.getName());
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("toSting", String.class);
        method.invoke(obj, "null");
    }

    public void toSting(String a) {
        System.out.println("hi " + a);
    }
```

P.S. Я понимаю, что пример учебный, но метод лучше назвать по-другому. Метод `toString()` определен в классе Object и обращение к нему обычно предполагает более-менее предсказуемый результат